# Как создать файл в vs code на c#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, пытаюсь создать файл на с# в vs code, пишу в консоли "dotnet new console", Создается несколько файлов, но в файле с расширением .cs вместо такого кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получается такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что делать, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: У вас новая версия C# теперь допустимо писать программы верхнего уровня, вот он и сгенерировал такой файл.

Comment: Это допустимый код для c# 9 [Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)

Comment: Также стоит перейти по ссылке указанной в комментарии, там рассказывается что это.